# MouseEvent on THREE.js 3d spheres do not trigger on the right place

Tags: javascript, d3.js, three.js, mouseevent, raycasting

I'm working on someone else's project to finish it, and it's pretty cool. It is supposed to be a diagram that will dynamically generate nodes(spheres) and be able to click on them and then a new diagram with related nodes will appear.

I am working on the clic kable part now, it seems harder than i thought. I have read into raycasting and vectors. I have even found examples that get pretty close to what i want: http://mrdoob.github.io/three.js/examples/canvas_interactive_cubes.html

BUT, for some reason when i hover next to the nodes (the hover spots seem very arbitrary, as highlighted in the image) they change color. For some most of them i cant even find the "hotspots". 
I think i lack some understanding of the unprojecting/converting/transformation from 3d to 2d part. And maybe that's why my mouse doesn't intersect properly with the nodes on screen i guess.

My onmousemove event:

```
function onDocumentMouseMove2(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        var canvasSvg= d3.select("#canvas-svg")[0][0];          
        mouse.x = ( event.clientX /  canvasSvg.clientWidth) * 2 - 1;
        mouse.y = - ( event.clientY / canvasSvg.clientHeight ) * 2 + 1;

        var vector = new THREE.Vector3(mouse.x, mouse.y, 1).unproject(camera);

        //raycaster.setFromCamera( mouse, camera );
        raycaster.set(camera.position, vector.sub(camera.position).normalize());

        var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( scene.children ); 

        //console logs
        console.log("current 'canvas' div");
        console.log(canvasSvg)

        console.log("mouse");
        console.log(mouse);

        console.log("vector");
        console.log(vector);



        if ( intersects.length > 0 ) {
            intersects[0].object.material.color.setHex( Math.random() * 0xffffff ); //gives another color to the node i hover over
            intersects[0].object.callback(); //this calls the funcion "callback" i attached to the nodes.
        }

        for ( var i in intersects ) {
                intersects[ i ].object.material.color.setHex( Math.random() * 0xffffff | 0x80000000 );
        }       
    }
```

My camera

```
        // Set camera attributes and create camera
    var VIEW_ANGLE = 7, //field of view
        ASPECT = WIDTH / HEIGHT, 
        //ASPECT  = $container[0].clientWidth / $container[0].clientHeight,
        NEAR = 0.1,
        FAR = 10000;
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(VIEW_ANGLE, ASPECT, NEAR, FAR);
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KIvCK.png

Answer (score 0):

Good day! I managed to fix it with this example:
http://jsfiddle.net/fek9ddg5/62/

```js
    mouse.x = ( ( event.clientX - renderer.domElement.offsetLeft ) / renderer.domElement.width ) * 2 - 1;
    mouse.y = - ( ( event.clientY - renderer.domElement.offsetTop ) / renderer.domElement.height ) * 2 + 1;
```

The ray was indeed confused on where it had to be projected. I had to take note of the offSet from the top of thescreen to my canvas.